# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<string>' to 'string'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

Code line causing the error:

```
Current_UserInfo.Current_First_Name = GetUser_Query.Select(m => m.First_Name).ToQueryString();
```

This is the error:

> Error CS0029
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'string'

I am getting user name (`environment`) and pulling there info from database (`IQueryable`). Than I am storing it into a model (`Current_UserInfo`) so that I can use it later.

```
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public Current_UserInfo_Model Current_UserInfo { get; set; } = default!;

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        // get user name 
        String user = System.Environment.UserName.ToString();

        // search useranme from database and pull there info
        IQueryable<Staff_Model> GetUser_Query = (from m in _context1.Staff_DbSet
                                                      where m.UserName.ToUpper().Contains(user.ToUpper())
                                                      select m);

        // save there info into another model so there isn't need connect to database again 
        Current_UserInfo.Current_UserName = user;
        Current_UserInfo.Current_First_Name = GetUser_Query.Select(m => m.First_Name);
        Current_UserInfo.Current_Last_Name = GetUser_Query.Select(m => m.Last_Name);

        return Page();
    }
```

I also tried the following function but it tries to convert object into string and can't get the value of `m.First_Name`:

```
 Current_UserInfo.Current_First_Name = GetUser_Query.Select(m => m.First_Name).ToQueryString();
 Current_UserInfo.Current_Last_Name = GetUser_Query.Select(m => m.Last_Name).ToString();
```

Comment: Select will return a list. When you know the result will be exactly one entry then use First instead.

Comment: I tried using `GetUser_Query.First(m => m.FIrst_Name)` but that gives an error `m.FIrst_Name maybe null here`

Comment: FYI, `System.Environment.UserName` is already a string. No need to call `ToString()` on it.

Comment: I meant to change "Select" in the GetUser_Query call.

Comment: then you can use FirstOrDefault. @Ralf comment explicitly said if YOU KNOW

Comment: Use FirstOrDefault() instead of First()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may just need to select the `FirstOrDefault` from the database, check it for `null`, and then use the data if it's not:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    // get user name 
    String userName = Environment.UserName;

    // search username from database and pull their info
    Staff_Model user = _context1.Staff_DbSet.FirstOrDefault(m =>
        m.UserName.ToUpper() == userName.ToUpper());

    // save info into another model so there isn't need connect to database again 
    Current_UserInfo.Current_UserName = userName;
    Current_UserInfo.Current_First_Name = user?.First_Name;
    Current_UserInfo.Current_Last_Name = user?.Last_Name;

    return Page();
}
```